# Avoiding page reloading in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

When i am hitting an URL from the browser i am loading the login page which extends the EntryPoint and implements the method onModuleLoad(). Inside onModuleLoad method i am adding the login page with a horizontal panel and also i have a link in the login page. when i click the link i have to hide the login page(X) and need to show an another page(Y) in the same horizontal panel without reloading the entire page or the root panel. both the pages(X&Y) added in the horizontal panel extends composite. but when i click the link it loads the another page(Y) but suddenly it reloads the entire page so that again the login page(X) renders.
Please suggest me how to avoid the reloading of entire or how to load the horizontal panel alone?

Comment: I think you need to post some relevant code. What is the `link` implemented as?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DeckPanel.

Add widget X and Y to the DeckPanel. Show widget X.
Add a ClickHandler to a Button or Label that will show widget Y when clicked.